# Wordpress and subdomains htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I currently have Wordpress installed in the base path of my server. Wordpress uses htaccess for user-friendly URL's. In addition I have the need of wildcarded subdomains, as I have users wanting to access a specific system.

When the user visits www.domain.com, or just domain.com, they should be served Wordpress. If they are requesting giraffesinafrica.domain.com, the dir should be set to /system/ (a folder in base path)

In the folder /system/ i have another .htaccess controlling the URLS redirected into that..

I hope someone can lead me on the way :)

Thanks in advance!

```
RewriteEngine On

# 3. internal redirect to the shop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/ [L,NC,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear enough.. My question is how to achieve the results what I described above. My code does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You talk about /system, while your code uses /subdomain, so I will use the latter.

```
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite subdomains to separate folder
RewriteRule ^subdomain/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
# or if you want to rewrite sub.domain.com/test to /subdomain/sub/test
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/%1/$1 [L]

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R]


# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You're code seems to work perfect, however I need to use www for the main domain, if no subdomain is requested. This is making my code seem like an endless loop? Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

#force domain setup to use www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# rewrite subdomains to separate folder
RewriteRule ^subdomain/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
# rewrite sub.domain.com/test to /subdomain/sub/test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/%1/$1 [L]

Comment: Do you want www.domain.com to redirect to domain.com, or the other way around? Your code above redirect domain.com to domain.com, which results in an endless loop.

Comment: I wanted it to add www to the domain, if just domain.com was requested. (hence www will never be used for other subdomains, and I don't want problems with duplicate content)

Comment: I changed my post so it will also force the www version and not use that one as a subdomain.

Comment: You are as sent from heaven. Thank you so much Gerben :)

Comment: In my country, today is a holiday where we give present to each other. So think of this as your 'sinterklaas'-present. :-P