# Only .php files loop with .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm setting up a system with wildcard subdomains directed to subfolders. For reasons beyond me, this has to be done with .htaccess. For instance, to redirect http://subdomain.example.com to the directory /subdomain/ under example.com's public_html, the following *partially* works (with thanks to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368473/wordpress-and-subdomains-htaccess)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdomain/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L]
```

It's working for all types of files *except* if they have extension .php. For example, if I drop a sometext.txt file in the /subdomain/ directory, I can get it at http://subdomain.example.com/sometext.txt but if I change the text file's extension to .php, I get a 500 error because of a redirect loop.

That makes me think that there's something strange going on with how the PHP module tries to read the file. Or something in the relationship between Apache and PHP. I'm not familiar with this; that's why I'm asking.

I'm on a shared host so I can't access the Apache configuration.

Comment: Also to note: If I browse to http://www.example.com/subdomain/sometext.php, it works. But http://subdomain.example.com/sometext.php loops.

Comment: what is the content of php? nothing special right? can you make it a simple echo 'hello' only

Comment: Probably the easiest way to get to the bottom of this would be to enable the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and have a look at what is happening.

Comment: Well here's an update. The presence of /subdomain/index.php was affecting the matter, and getting rid of it revealed that all .php files get redirected  in the following manner:
subdomain.example.com/somefile.php -> "/subdomain/index.php/subdomain/somefile.php" (that's a 404). So someone's remapping the / to /index.php and then the rewrite rule gets confused... But this only happens with .php requests.

Comment: @fedmich The content of the php is "this is some sample text", not even a <?php start tag.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig I'd love to, but I can't.

Comment: is there an .htaccess in the parent folders? it can overwrite your current .htaccess if there is

Comment: @fedmich No there isn't. So it must be something in Apache config, which I can't access.

Comment: this shouldn't be an Apache config issue, as you are on shared hosting and I bet they are compliant enough and wouldnt cause you this issue.

Comment: @fedmich it actually was something like that, I'm posting the answer now.

Comment: ok, good to know that its fixed. can you close this question so its marked as fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the problem was caused by the hosting provider's configuration. The .htaccess is fine. I'm told this is a recently discovered issue in DirectAdmin with php-fpm and FastCgi. (The solution was for them to remove a symlink to public_html at my home directory and replace it with an empty directory. I don't know any more about this!)

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if doing it like this works for you?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.localhost$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/subdomain/$1 [L]
```

so instead of localhost, try adding directly your actual domain url.

I tested this on my localhost, with such urls first, and then they redirect correctly

```
http://subdomain.localhost/test.txt
http://subdomain.localhost/test.php
```

---

I'll suggest relax a bit, take coffee and comeback. (sometimes this helps)

Then focus on just the redirection,

- rule out issue of their Apache config
- you can worry bout 301 later
- work with test.php only, no index.php

try this on your debugging:

- close all other chrome browser tabs.
- open in incognito, the url you want to test
- keep closing that incognito so its always for sure a full refresh
- change htacess file, and always open a new incognito tab

Comment: Yes that works as I pointed out at the first comment to my original question, but that's not a solution since it's a 302 redirect that eats away the subdomain.example.com.

Comment: Did you tried my code? If you noticed on line 2 of your code, RewriteRule ^subdomain/ - [L] <- this is what it redirects loop

Comment: Actually that line stops the loop. It's either that or RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain - otherwise _everything_ loops.

Comment: Try without that line first