# .htaccess modification works locally but not on production

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have some modifications to Wordpress's .htaccess file which another app to run in the same directory (see below). As you can see, we insert a few RewriteCond that tell WP rewrites to ignore specific requests to our other app's controllers.

We just added one more rule (it's commented below), and it works exactly as expected on two local development environments (one MAMP the other XAMP). BUt when we push it to our production server, the new rule doesn't seem to have any effect. Instead of being able to navigate to files in the new directory (/app/resumes/stamped/123.pdf), we see the Wordpress "Well this is embarrassing" message, indicating that the request is still being routed through Wordpress.

mod_rewrite is definitely working and `AllowOverride All` is set in production. What else can we check to get this to work in production?

For me the strangest part is that the OTHER `RewriteCond` DO work, so I'm really puzzled about why just this one new line should behave so differently in the production environment.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

###This is the new rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/app/resumes/stamped/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Update**

This is what lives in the .htaccess in /app

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/

#This is new too
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resumes/stamped/

RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

**Update 2**
We just learned that requests sent WITH the username/password authorization (I'm using Chromes's REST extension to add the necessary headers manually) required by the /stamped directory's .htaccess file DO succeed. In other words, it basically IS working but we can't tell because we're expecting it to prompt for the username / password since it does this on all the other servers. So the real question is why does the authorization prompt (or lack thereof) land us on Wordpress's 404 page on this server?

**Update 3**

This is the htaccess file in .../stamped

```
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "restricted area"
 AuthUserFile /home/username/public_html/.htpasswd
 require valid-user
```

The path to the .htpasswd file differs from dev to production, of course.

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/app` OR any where below that directory?

Comment: Yes. I have one in /app which I will update above now.

Comment: Ah my gut feeling was right then :P

Comment: So as per this .htaccess you are rewriting `/app/resumes/stamped/123.pdf)` to `/app/webroot/resumes/stamped/123.pdf`

Comment: @anubhava What are you thinking? I don't think that the request is even getting to the second .htaccess file because I'm seeing the Wordpress 404 page (almost definitely resulting from the rewrite in the root).

Comment: No its not because of parent .htaccess. You can move away `/app/.htaccess` and test it.

Comment: It still doesn't work when I comment everything in /app/.htaccess. I still land on Wordpress 404 page.

Comment: Hmm pretty strange. Is it still going to `/index.php` ?

Comment: @anubhava It must be because I see the Wordpress 404 page: "Well this is embarrassing..."

Comment: Just `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` would have been enough. Make sure there is no other conflicting rule and no other .htaccess is in play. Hopefully `DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/resumes/stamped/123.pdf` is a valid file.

Comment: We just learned something new (see update above).

Comment: Hmm ok I'm not surprised about this behavior. Can you post your `/stamped directory's .htaccess file`?

Comment: Just a little something I noticed... Might be insignificant but you wrote (in quotes) that's it's saying _Well this is embarrassing..._ However unless I'm mistaken, that error message is a Firefox message -- not Wordpress. Wordpress _does_ have a similar message when you use one of the default themes that says _This is somewhat embarrassing, isn't it?_ but I believe they're two totally different matters. Unless you just accidentally misquoted, in which case feel free to disregard this comment. ;)

Comment: I must have misquoted. It's the default WP 404 page, with the search bar, etc. The htaccess in /stamped will be added above in 90 seconds.

Comment: You might try explicitly adding an ErrorDocument line for a 403. This might prevent it from leaning on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on Apache servers with DirectAdmin, PHP-FPM and FastCGI that manifests in weird .htaccess behavior. I once spent an evening trying to figure it out: [Only .php files loop with .htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287882/only-php-files-loop-with-htaccess-redirect/14289084) The above might or might not apply to you, but if everything's ok on a local server but not on a production server, I'd look for the problem there.